# Where Eclipse stores working set configuration

Tags: eclipse

Looks my workspace somehow is corrupted and I have created new one with new project checkout to it. But I was using working set in crashed system that is not stored in repository. How I can retrieve this info? Where Eclipse stores it's working set configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working set definitions are stored in the `workingsets.xml` file in the workspace `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench` directory.