# Set Eclipse Configuration Folder

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse is corrupting at least one of my workspaces on a weekly basis, and I'm trying to fix this problem. I assume it's because I have multiple Eclipse distributions and workspaces; neither is something I can change.

So I further assume the problem is because Eclipse tends to store data in at least four folders, and this data is not compatible between let's say Mars and Luna:

- the workspace folder (one workspace usually corresponds to one Eclipse distribution, so this folder is not critical)
- the folder Eclipse resides in (again, one per distribution, so not critical)
- *[username]/.eclipse*
- *[username]/.swt*
- probably some more

Is there any way to force Eclipse to only use one folder to store it's configuration (or whatever), so I can rule out that different Eclipse distributions affect each other?

Comment: have a look at this, this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160686/where-eclipse-stores-working-set-configuration?rq=1

Comment: @piyushjaiswal That question is about working sets, I'm talking about whatever is inside the *.eclipse* and *.swt* folders.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can maintain default work space folder change from one eclipse to another its enough. And corrupting eclipse for every week strage .

Comment: It's also strange that [Mars doesn't support plug-in unit tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657010/junit-plug-in-tests-ignoring-target-platform) (which is part of why I need multiple Eclipses in the first place), still still stuff like that keeps happening, and not only for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are options for exactly that

- **osgi.instance.area.default** (workspace)
- **osgi.configuration.area** (settings)

They're useable on commandline and/or eclipse.ini with -vmargs and -D(-prefix) like so

`eclipse -vmargs -Dosgi.instance.area.default=/path/to/workspace -Dosgi.configuration.area=/path/to/settings`

http://www.alim-oezdemir.de/eclipse-commandline-option-for-workspace-and-settings/